# Is there any way to compress a video in Android native app?

Tags: android, compression, optimization, mp4parser, nativeapplication

I am working on an Android native application with video recording. Everything works like a charm but video uploading is very slow.

I'm using mp4parser for Pause/Record. I tried reference of Video compression API but I couldn't find anything.

Is there any way, I can implement the video compression. Your earliest response would be appreciated.

Thank you all!!!!

Comment: Hi @Sudharsan have u got any solution to compress video?

Answer (score 1):

If you are recording video with Intent you can use this flag:

intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1); //1 for high and 0 for low quality.

About uploading?

How do you upload? via multipart-data ? I have an example for uploading that without any errors (OOM)

Comment: Thanks for your response andDev, I'm not using "intent" to record the video. I used customized android media recorder to record the video and using the same "multipart-data" uploading. uploading is fine so I need some compressing methodology before upload.